# How to disable Alt+F4 and Alt+Tab functionality for Windows 7, to use it on Kiosk?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, kiosk

How do I disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality for Windows 7? I would like to use it as a Kiosk.

Is this possible, with any software, tricks or registry hacks?

Answer (score 1):

Pluck off the keys

Write a program to capture the keys then exit the sub routine

Use GPEdit to disable Ctrl Alt Delete

Set the shell to the program so the system shuts down if it ever closes